# How to get the numpy function to perform operation only on the same set of indexes from two different arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have four arrays:

per_1_start_time = [[Timestamp('2014-01-20 13:06:00+0100', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(60)')] [Timestamp('2014-02-04 10:31:00+0100', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(60)')]]

per_1_stop_time = [[Timestamp('2014-01-20 13:10:11.372000+0100', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(60)')] [Timestamp('2014-02-04 10:35:47.338000+0100', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(60)')]]

per_2_start_time = [[Timestamp('2014-01-20 13:08:00+0100', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(60)')] [Timestamp('2014-01-20 13:08:00+0100', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(60)')]]

per_2_stop_time = [[Timestamp('2014-01-20 13:09:03.472000+0100', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(60)')] [Timestamp('2014-01-20 13:09:03.472000+0100', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(60)')]]

I want to find how long person1 was with person2 (if at all)

This is what I tried (sorry for this horrible syntax, im very new to this):

intersept_loc = []

if np.less(per_1_start_time, per_2_start_time).any() & np.greater(per_1_stop_time, per_2_start_time).any():
intersept_loc.append(np.subtract(per_1_stop_time, per_2_start_time))
elif np.greater(per_1_start_time, per_2_start_time).any() & np.greater(per_2_stop_time, per_1_start_time).any():
intersept_loc.append(np.subtract(per_2_stop_time, per_1_start_time))
elif np.less(per_1_start_time, per_2_start_time).any() & np.greater(per_1_stop_time, per_2_stop_time).any():
intersept_loc.append(np.subtract(per_2_stop_time, per_2_start_time))
elif np.greater(per_1_start_time, per_2_start_time).any() & np.less(per_1_stop_time, per_2_stop_time).any():
intersept_loc.append(np.subtract(per_1_stop_time, per_1_start_time))
else: intersept_loc.append(0)

print(intersept_loc3)

This is what I get:
array([[Timedelta('0 days 00:02:11.372000')], [Timedelta('14 days 21:27:47.338000')]], dtype=object)]
The first time delta is right, but it also performs function on the second row, which I don't want. If anyone can give some guidance I would be very grateful

Comment: [Please format your code properly.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I guess it will work.

```
from datetime import timedelta

# arrays shoould have the same length
assert len(per_1_start_time) == len(per_1_stop_time) == len(per_2_start_time) == len(per_2_stop_time)

intersect_times = []
for p1_start, p1_stop, p2_start, p2_stop in zip(per_1_start_time, per_1_stop_time, per_2_start_time, per_2_stop_time):
    latest_start = max(p1_start, p2_start)
    earliest_end = min(p1_stop, p2_stop)
    overlap = (earliest_end - latest_start).total_seconds()
    overlap = max(0, overlap)
    intersect_times.append(timedelta(seconds=overlap))

print(intersect_times)
```

Comment: @Andrey Matveev does it work?